# Jailkit on a Mac: "ERROR: <jaildir> is not owned by root:root!" / "ERROR: jail directory <jaildir> is not safe"

Tags: mac, ssh, chroot-jail

I'm trying to create a jailed user for limited SSH access on my Mac. I have been, for the most part, following the directions in [this Ubuntu StackExchange answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93411/simple-easy-way-to-jail-users).

However, I'm getting stuck:

```
# First, added `root` group via System Preferences > Users & Groups
# (`/sbin/groupadd` is not present on macOS)

$ sudo chown root:root /Users/jail
$ ls -ld /Users/jail
drwxr-xr-x+ 13 root  root  442 Jan 12 15:21 /Users/jail
$ sudo /usr/local/Cellar/jailkit/2.19/sbin/jk_init -v /Users/jail basicshell
ERROR: /Users/jail is not owned by root:root!

ERROR: jail directory /Users/jail is not safe
```

[This mailing list message](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/jailkit-users/2007-09/msg00014.html) looks relevant, but I'm not 100% sure (basically, jailkit wants the entire directory tree leading up to the chroot jail to be owned by `root:root`... but `/` is owned by `root:wheel` by default on a Mac).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.